# Python __init__.py, less polluted namespace

Tags: python, package

I have a directory structure

```
foobar/
    __init__.py
    baz.py
```

where `__init__.py` is just

```
from .baz import do_something
```

and `baz.py`

```
def do_something():
    return
```

Now, when I do `import foobar`, I get access to

```
foobar
foobar.do_something()
```

Nice! However, one also has

```
foobar.baz
```

although it's never explicitly imported. I suppose it has been imported along with `do_something`.

Is there a way to make `do_something` available as `foobar.do_something` without adding `foobar.baz` to the namespace? (And without putting everything in in `__init__.py`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is documented in [chapter 5 of the Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules). If you *really* want to disable it, you can do this in `__init__.py`:

```
from .baz import do_something
del baz
```

which removes `baz` from `foobar`'s namespace when imported.

However, this isn't common practice as far as I know; is there a particular reason you're wanting to do this?

Comment: Not really, it's just that `baz` doesn't contribute anything and I wanted to be more opinionated about it. Anyhow, your explanation is good enough. Thanks!